# Почему не меняет фон?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не меняет фон?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function bg_change() {
      $('.button_change')
        .animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 'slow', function() {
          $(this)
            .css({
              'background-image': 'url(/img/button/btn_hover.jpg)'
            })
            .animate({
              opacity: 1
            });
        }).toggle(1000).animate({
            opacity: 0
          }, 'slow', function() $(this)
          .css({
            'background-image': 'url(/img/button/btn.jpg)'
          })
          .animate({
            opacity: 1
          });
        })(); bg_change();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button_change"></div>
```

Comment: скобки проверьте

Comment: @qzavyer, скобки, неправильное использование функции animate(), неожиданное toggle(), которое скрывает вообще всё, тут прям целый триллер, а не просто скобки :)

Answer (score 1):

что-то тут странное. Если поправить форматирование, скобки и убрать ненужный toggle, то получится что-то вроде этого:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(
          function() {
             var bg_change = function (){
                $('.button_change')
                        .animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow',
                        function() {
                           $(this)
                                   .css({'background-color': 'black'})
                                   //.animate({opacity: 1});
                        })
                        .animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow',
                        function(){
                           $(this)
                                   .css({'background-color': 'red'})
                                   //.animate({opacity: 1});
                        });
             };
             bg_change();
          });
</script>
```

не уверен правда, что это то, что вы хотели..

Comment: Спасибо. Уже нашел решение, вот мой код, мож кому пригодиться:
<div class="button_change"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

     (function bg_change(){
      $('.button_change')
      .animate( '1500', function() {
       $(this)
       .css({'background-image': 'url(/img/button/btn_hover.jpg)'})
      });
      $('.button_change')
      .animate( '1500', function() {
       $(this)
       .css({'background-image': 'url(/img/button/btn.jpg)', 'z-index':'2'})
      });
      bg_change();
     })() ;
    });
   </script>